# Format textbox with default value to show 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have text boxes in my page and i am showing default values in them, values are coming from database and having 4 decimal places however i want to show only two decimal places, I tried putting format #,##0.00 but this did not work, below in code i am creating textbox and assigning default value

```
<input type="text" name="tproj" id="{concat('txtboxAdjustment', position())}" value="{@proj}" style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;height:15px;width:90px;text-align:right;" onKeyPress="return validateKeyPress(this,event)" onkeyup="return validateKeyUp(this,event);" onblur="calculate_elect_total()" />
```

Comment: You could always format them on the server side code where you are pulling or even in the db query. Bits are cheap show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

[**toFixed()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will help you in javascript.  But I'm not sure how to add this in your case.

Try below

```
value = @proj.toFixed(2);  //Not sure in your case
```

**EDIT:** A sample code:

```
var no = 22.333333;
alert(no.toFixed(2));  //returns 22.33
```

Comment: @Animesh As I already mentioned, this is a way in javascript.  But in your case what is `@proj`/ is it serverside code? need more information on this.

Comment: I think you need to imporove your example to set toFixed value back to input box like `document.getElementById('proj').value = document.getElementById('proj').value.toFixed(2);`

Comment: yes it is a server side value, however this is done now what i tried was : {format-number(@proj,'#0.00')} and this worked :D, Thanks everyone for helping me out on this as i am new to it. Thanks again

Comment: @Animesh Oh, you got it.  Glad to hear :)  Is it ASP.NET?